# Keras mulilabel classification loss function: how to get accurate val_acc using binary crossentropy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am following this tutorial on multilabel-classification using keras https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/classifying-genres-of-movies-by-looking-at-the-poster-a-neural-approach/

Here it is suggested to use the `binary_crossentropy` as a loss function and `sigmoid` for classification. However, I realize that the val_acc is wrong as it is quite high 80-90% right from the start, like so:

```
Train on 9000 samples, validate on 1000 samples
Epoch 1/5
9000/9000 [==============================] - 900s - loss: 0.2352 - acc: 0.9194 - val_loss: 0.2022 - val_acc: 0.9278
```

Is there any way to get an accurate val_acc during training within a multilabel classification context?

Update: I see that some have suggested (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10371) using "tanh+hinge with {-1, 1}". How would I implement that in keras?

Comment: How are the classes in the dataset distributed? This could be a sign of a poor dataset. It is mentioned in the tutorial that "drama" is overrepresented. Try to see what your model actually predicts.